# Typescript generic abstract class - Why doesn't this abstract method inherit the class type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I come from a background in C# and I'm currently trying to get my head around Typescript. I've run in to the following issue while creating a generic abtract class in Typescript, and I'm not sure if it's a problem with my implementation, or a limitation of the language:

Given the following abstract class, and class extending it:

```
abstract class Filter<T> {
    value T;
    abstract apply<T>(items: T[]): T[];
}

class StringFilter extends Filter<string> {
    apply(items: string[]) {
        return items.filter(i => this.value === i);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Property 'apply' in type 'StringFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter<string>'.
Type '(items: string[]) => string[]' is not assignable to type '<T>(items: T[]) => T[]'.
```

In C# I would have expected the apply method to share the same generic type as the class, but in Typescript this doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I make sure that a type of `Filter<string>` has an apply method of type `(items: string[]) => string[]`?

Comment: For clarity, your code is equivalent to this: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYgS2RAplADwAqAfAgN4BQCdCAbsMgK74CEAXAiQNy31QkGPATAADuOQBPIgFUyACmwEAtmG5yA2gF0AlJt38AvtWoo0GAMrRsAOwDmOPIQT4AHgTsATDM4LEwvYOFDT0YpIyymoaCEGOunpUAuF0UPgQLFB2CCr46gB0AGa4AcoIALwUEAAW2GAFTKz4lRUVuXr84abGQA) - you've just introduced a *different* generic parameter that's *also* called `T` but is not the `T` for the class. I've just renamed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to provide the generic parameter to `apply`. The following modification of your code compiles without issues.

```
abstract class Filter<T> {
    value: T;
    abstract apply(items: T[]): T[];
}

class StringFilter extends Filter<string> {
    apply(items: string[]) {
        return items.filter(i => this.value === i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `<T>` from the abstract apply method.

> How can I make sure that a type of Filter has an apply method of type (items: string[]) => string[]?

Well, you're already doing that. The definition of the abstract method "apply" is already ensuring your request.
Setting the abstract class as generic, all the methods/props defined will inherit the `T` specification in the concrete class.